# How to copy the excel data with cell border?

Tags: excel

I have data filled in cell. But when i copy  the  those cells/rows (`CTRL + C)`and paste it in outlook, data is displayed without cell and row border . How  can i copy data with border lines ?

Comment: May I suggest posting this on a stack exchange site that is more suited to "general software use" StackOverflow is more about programming questions.

Answer (score 0):

When you paste the data into Outlook click the Paste/Ctrl box that appers and under Paste Options click the first icon, Keep Original Table Formatting.

Seems to only work when more than one cell is copied.

Answer (score 0):

When you paste into outlook select "Keep Source Formatting" in the paste menu, it should carry over all the borders.